# Rails: How to add id to link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @machines.each do |machine|%>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', edit_machine_path(machine.id), class: "btn btn-danger", id: 'machine_#{machine.id}',remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

I want to add id to link, but `id: 'machine_#{machine.id}'` does not work. 
Is there a way to generate id like machine_1 , machine_2 ....?

Comment: JFYI, you can use resource directly for generating urls, `edit_machine_path(machine)`.

Comment: try adding double quotes instead of single quote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes while interpolating

replace

```
id: 'machine_#{machine.id}'
```

with

```
id: "machine_#{machine.id}"
```

so

```
<% @machines.each do |machine|%>
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', edit_machine_path(machine.id), class: "btn btn-danger", id: "machine_#{machine.id}",remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.